# How to connect NodeJS' API from AngularJS docker container from the browser?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, azure, docker, docker-compose

I've two docker containers which are AngularJS and NodeJS applications. I'm using Azure App Service with Multi-Container docker configuration. I have docker compose file for my application and using the same in Azure App Service. From the browser, I got the application's UI screen once I click on the button it should call an API from NodeJS but It is not happening though. My Dockerfiles and docker compose file are very simple and straight forward.

I have provided `nodejs` as container name for NodeJS application and mentioned the same name in AngularJS code to access the API but it is not working from the browser.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  angularjs:
    container_name: 'angularjs'
    image: 'ui:1'
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    depends_on:
      - 'nodejs'
  nodejs:
    container_name: 'nodejs'
    image: 'api:1'
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
```

In the AngularJS code, I'm using `http://nodejs:4000/data` and it is a `GET` method. In this way, I'm facing an error `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Comment: Can you please add `docker-compose.yml` over here

Comment: you can not access `http://nodejs:4000/data` this from browser, as container name are only for service to service communication and these are only understandable by docker not by the browser, browser need IP address or domain that is reachable.